# default weight measurement?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

What's the default weight measurement? Is it in pound or gram?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27257/default-weight-measurement?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Duh me,

Found the answer. It's the KG by default.
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0